# Google Sheets custom sidebar

Tags: google-sheets, hyperlink, google-apps-script-editor

I have a very long google sheets document. I often have to go to a specific area of that document to input data. I want to have a sidebar with designated hyperlinks to areas in the document to minimize the time it takes to get to the area I need to edit. How can I create a sidebar that reads links from a hidden tab displaying all the links I want displayed in the sidebar?

Answer (score 0):

most likely it's not possible as you imagine it. instead, take a look on hyperlink jumps... right-click the cell you want to jump in and select **Get link to this cell**:

[image: 0]

then just paste it in your separate sheet or side column/frozen row

to make it nicer you can use `HYPERLINK` formula and assign some short alias

Comment: Thank you for the idea and for your time.